# Batch-script to search a specific directory for all instances of *.xml files

Tags: batch-file

I've come upon this so far:

```
for /r . %%g in (*.xml) do echo %%g
```

But I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to specify a path for it to search. For instance, I need to see all the XML files in Z:\abc\def\ directory and all sub-directories.

Thanks in advance for looking at this!

Comment: That looks like a Unix shell script, but the directory you specify seems to have a DOS name.

Comment: No this is a .bat script, I have tried and tested it successfully via the windows command line. I'm just a little stuck as to how to specify a path for it to search, which might be different than the one where this script resides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My goodness... you were 99% there.

The dot after the /R option represents the current directory. Simply substitute the specific path you want.

```
for /r "Z:\abc\def" %%g in (*.xml) do echo %%g
```

If all you are trying to do is list the files on the screen, then you can use the DIR command:

```
dir /b /s /a-d "Z:\abc\def\*.xml"
```

Comment: *banging head against desk* THANK YOU!

Comment: Yep, all I need is to list off the files as they will feed a 3rd party program. Between the two methods you listed, which one is more efficient, resource wise?

Comment: I haven't done any timing tests, but there is overhead with the FOR statement iterating each file. The DIR option should be faster, though I don't know if it will be significant.